# How to use Formspree with a Bootstrap template

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to adapt [W3 school's "Company" Bootstrap theme](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) to a website of which a draft version is at [www.peek.solutions](http://www.peek.solutions).

The theme comes with a contact form which doesn't yet work, and I'm trying to use [Formspree](https://formspree.io/) to make it do so. My approach so far has simply been to 'wrap' the part containing the form fields with a `<form>` tag following with an `action="https://formspree.io/kurt.peek@gmail.com"` and `method=POST`, following the documentation:

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/kurt.peek@gmail.com" method="POST">
<div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

However, this does not seem to work: when I fill out some test values in the fields and press "Send", I do not see Formspree's default confirmation page, nor do I receive an e-mail at the given address (see below).

[image]

How can I fix this code to make Formspree work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by following the example on https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-a-formspree-form-to-your-static-sites--cms-23870. Here is the updated snippet:

```
<form id="contactform" action="//formspree.io/kurt.peek@gmail.com" method="POST">
<div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="//peek.solutions/confirmation.html" />
<input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />   
</form>
```

I'm still having some issues with getting the `_next` input to re-direct to my own confirmation page rather than Formspree's default one, but that's a separate issue.